# How to use websockets with ionnic and android?

Tags: android, cordova, websocket, ionic-framework

So I have tried with two cordova plugins:

https://github.com/knowledgecode/WebSocket-for-Android

and

https://github.com/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket

it is supposed to make websockets work on android(I use 4.1 avd) but neighter does. When I create a websocket I get the error:
ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined

any ideas? Websocket works out of the box for android 5

Comment: Scince there is little interest here I asked on ionic forum as well: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/websocket-with-android-and-ionic/20228

Comment: I used didint use  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // called when ready
  }); it works now

Answer (score 5):

I am using [socket.io](http://socket.io/) with ionic
Have a look at this:
[angularjs+socket.io](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/)
(as ionic uses angularjs)
You can also use sockjs.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems socket.io works best with its own server and I have a backend in Play Framework. Also in older androids it would probably fall on long polling(a guess) and I'd rather not implement this on server. So I need to add support for websockets with one of this plugins.

Comment: hello fares, I'm trying to use socket.io for Ionic 5. And for some reason even if I apply the documentation couldn't apply it on Ionic 5. Can you help me?